# Only one Visual Studio instance when Alt-tabbing

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab, visual-studio-2013

I have an annoying problem that is either rare or I just can't find the right keywords to describe it to Google.

I use W7, and always have several Visual Studio (2013) instances opened at once. I often need to switch from one to another, but Alt+Tab only shows one VS instance. Actually it sometimes shows me several instances, but they seem to "merge" when I switch from one to the other with ALT+TAB. This does not happen for other applications, and I don't remember having this problem in the past.

I turned Aero off, but the classic theme works exactly the same.

Edit: for some reason the problem is not happening anymore right now and I'm not sure why. I did put both currently running instances side by side on the screen (Win+Right, Win+Left), and now that both windows are maximized again, the merging doesn't occur anymore... Correlation or cause?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605443/multiple-windows-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks, I had already read this issue, and I don't think this is the same. I don't want to switch between editor windows within one VS instance, I want to switch between instances.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the reason the problem went away is that at first you weren't using two actual *instances* of MSVS, you instead had dragged a dockable sub window outside the original, creating two separate windows. When I try to use alt tab to switch between these, it won't let me (infuriating!).

However, if I start two actual instances (via using the MSVS shortcut twice, for instance), I can switch using alt tab.

If you, or anyone else, knows how to solve the former problem, I'd love to know!

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: @DavidPostill I disagree my answer was simply stating I also had the problem. Moreover, my low reputation prevented me from commenting on the question or upvoting, which admittedly would have been more appropriate. However I provided relevant information (two instances versus multiple undocked windows of one instance) that the OP could possibly use to solve his problem, depending on his usage needs.